# using css to hide <th> elements except the first one

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

with CSS, i want to hide all the TH elements except the first one, i had the format like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

i need to check a solution for IE8 too as i know they do not support Pseudo Elements, I am trying like this

```
th:not(:first-child):display:none;
```

but this does not work on any browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`first-child` is not a pseudo-element, it's a pseudo-class. In any case, `:not` accepts only a "simple selector"; `first-child` does not qualify. But here you cannot use `first-child` anyway, since it applies to elements with a common parent.

In this case, you presumably want to hide the `th` not within the first `table`. So

```
th                   { display: none;  }
table:first-child th { display: block; }
```

This is a standard CSS idiom used in the case of "apply a value of X1 to some property for all Y, except in  case Z apply value X2". In a normal programming language, one might use an `if` statement involving a `not` operator. In CSS, taking advantage of the principle of order of rules, you write this as:

```
Y { property: X1; }    // standard behavior comes first
Z ( property: X2; }    // exceptional behavior comes next
```

In your case, the "standard behavior" is to hide the `th`, and the "exceptional behavior" is to show it for the first one.

You may be able to use `:not` in such situations, but it will not always behave as you expect, especially when combined with other selectors including other `:not`s, not to mention the "simple selector" restriction.

Comment: what about IE8, i need to fix for IE8 also

Comment: Check authoritative sources, such as MDN, or caniuse (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2). `:first-child` is part of CSS2 and is supported in all imaginable browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can do it easily like

$( "th:not(:first)" ).css( "background", "green" );

```js
$( "th:not(:first)" ).css( "background", "green" );

// "th:not(:first)" ).css( "display", "none" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```